# What is the most efficient way to do check if a value exist then Update or Insert in Sql

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to update date a value in table if it does not exist then it must be inserted

What is the best way to does this in MySql

Currently I am using

```
   SELECT Id INTO LId  FROM ATABLE WHERE ID = FID;
   IF LId IS NULL THEN
     INSERT INTO ATABLE(abc) Values (2)
   ELSE
     UPDATE ATABLE Set Abc = 2 Where Id = LId
   END IF;
```

But this hits the Database 3 times

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: I don't use mysql much, but I thought it had upserts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

That's what you're looking for :)

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for more details.

Comment: The MERGE statement is more nearly standard SQL, but it appears that MySQL does not have that (yet) - v5.4 manual does not mention it, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/17/3-ways-to-write-upsert-and-merge-queries-in-mysql/) if what you need.

I use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 3):

For MySql Upsert, you might want to check out this [blog post](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/02/21/flexible-insert-and-update-in-mysql/).  It highlights a few methods including doing an update and then an insert with a left-join:

```
update t1 as l
    inner join t2 as r on l.a = r.d
    set l.b = r.e, l.c = r.f;

insert into t1 (a, b, c)
    select l.d, l.e, l.f
    from t2 as l
        left outer join t1 as r on l.d = r.a
    where r.a is null;
```

A single statement upsert is possible using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE:

```
insert into t1(a, b, c)
    select d, e, f from t2
    on duplicate key update b = e, c = f;
```